# how to replay board games using html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html5-video

Is it possible to replay board game (for example, chess) moves as html5 video with configurable delay between two moves.

As this is a common requirement for almost all games, I hope there should be a standard way to do this.

One way is drawing moves using JavaScript and DOM manipulation, but I am trying to give it native html5 video user experience.

Comment: HTML5 video is for playing a video. Do you have a video of the game? If not, then you can't do it that way.

Comment: I don't have a video. I have game moves (~4kb, Json format, interpretation varies depending on the game).

I can give a relevant example here. With Samsung galaxy sIII, users can edit and send slides (separates by '-') from SMS app. These slides can be previewed using native video player.

Comment: That sounds more like a feature of Samsung's video/sms app than of HTML5 video.

Comment: no, that's just an example of a video player playing a custom content (text/SMS). :)

Comment: I'd say it's an example of an OS performing some proprietary magic between its apps. Doesn't mean that their video player supports custom events at all.

Answer (score 2):

The supported video formats of html5 video are OGG, H.264, Theora and WebM

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats

- If you can encode your gameplay to one of those formats (but prefererably all for compatability), you can play it in the html5 `video` object
- If you're looking to draw and manipulate graphics on a html page, you can use the `canvas` object
- If you're content with just moving graphics around, you can use `Javascript` and `CSS`

Comment: option **(1)** is an ideal solution.

Comment: Why is that the ideal solution? Any browser that would understand the `video` tag should also support `canvas`, which is much more lightweight both for the browser and server. Assuming that your game is written in canvas or javascript, replaying the game using those techniques would be trivial in comparison. If you still want a `video` object, what are your tools? You should try to find a solution how to convert graphics to video on the fly with the tools at your disposal (php/asp/.net/java/isapi dll's installed on your web server etc etc...)

Comment: ideal solution in the sense, it would give native client video play experience, and it can be posted to youtube. as we go to option 2 and 3 everything gets simpler. if I could do option (1) with the ease of option (3), then that would be awesome (an video player that plays custom format; provided, a decoder).

Comment: There's no easy way to accomplish what you ask for. The good news is that with Javascript/CSS/Canvas you can fairly easily build your own "video player" that does whatever you want. Granted, it won't go fullscreen in a  native way nor have native controls, but it'll be much more lightweight and faster than downloading a full video, especially over a cellular network. If you want a demo of your game to upload to youtube, use screen recording software. And add the appropriate "share" buttons to your gameplay video player and you can still go viral. :)

Comment: I will go with option (3), HTML + js + CSS only solution, because it is easy to start with.

Answer (score -1):

try to add loop attribute for your video tag once the video finish the playing again it starts form starting.

loop="loop"